# SSAS Mdx Use Strtomember to make the following MDX query dynamic with currentmember

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have the following MDX query which computes the Active Opportunities asofdate(defined by greater than start date and less than close date)

This works when the date values are hard coded. But I want it to work with .currentmember which takes the member in the hierarchy and computes the open opportunities between two dates

```
with member

[Measures].[Cumulative_count_dates]
as 
AGGREGATE(
{NULL:[Time Dimension].[Year-Qtr-Month-Date].[Date].&[2011-10-09T00:00:00]} * {[Opportuntity Close Dt].[Year-Qtr-Month-Date].[Date].&[2011-10-11T00:00:00] : NULL} 

 , [Measures].[Opportunities Count]
)

select {[Measures].[Cumulative_count_dates]} on columns,
NON EMPTY {[Time Dimension].[Year-Qtr-Month-Date].members} on rows
from AdventCube
```

In other words, I want to pass this as a variable

```
[Time Dimension].[Year-Qtr-Month-Date].[Date].&[2011-10-09T00:00:00]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with CurrentMember?

```
with member

[Measures].[Cumulative_count_dates]
as 
AGGREGATE(
{NULL:[Time Dimension].[Year-Qtr-Month-Date].CurrentMember} * {[Opportuntity Close Dt].[Year-Qtr-Month-Date].[Date].&[2011-10-11T00:00:00] : NULL} 

 , [Measures].[Opportunities Count]
)

select {[Measures].[Cumulative_count_dates]} on columns,
NON EMPTY {[Time Dimension].[Year-Qtr-Month-Date].[Date].members} on rows
from AdventCube
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with currentmember but I am getting incorrect results when I use it...So figured I will dynamically pass the actual string to construct the mdx query for each date possible.

Comment: I'm not sure. Could you please provide incorrect and correct results?